# type of file asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, types

How we can know type of file in asp.net ?

Comment: @Anish: It's unclear what file you're referring to. Perhaps a file being posted to your application?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the extension of the file then you can use the FileInfo class.

Use the [FileSystemInfo.Extension Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx)

Comment: Am creating the excel file using spread xml tags.. and use content-type as vmd.xml while getting it to the client side. But at this type file type is .xml by default(even though extention is .xls).

So i need to know the type is .xml not .xls
Can i get the same using FileSystemInfo.Extension Property